# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'rbuckridge@example.com' for key 'users_email_unique'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Here is the migration code:

```
    <?php
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
    
    class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
    {
        /**
         * Run the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('first_name');
                $table->string('last_name');
                $table->text('bio');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
                $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                $table->string('password');
                $table->string('profile_picture');
                $table->rememberToken();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    
        /**
         * Reverse the migrations.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function down()
        {
            Schema::dropIfExists('users');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this on a table that already has data? The error is pretty straightforward.

Comment: That migration has nothing to do with that error, you must have some migration or seeder that changes data on that table

Comment: I guess you are entering one email twice and email is unique.

Answer (score 0):

The migration has less contribution to the error you are getting. This because at this point the error indicates that the `rbuckridge@example.com` is already existaing with the user table. This is achieved with the `->unique()` method which prevent same data being re-entered in the same table column.

My suggestion is try to clear all the data first in the table and re enter the mail or use another different mail.